# hive clarifications on json and insert

Tags: json, hive

1)I want to try the examples in the below link related to JSON.when i check in internet i found so many JSON SerDe's.
Not sure which one i need to use and also what is the difference between each one?

http://thornydev.blogspot.in/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html

2)I am new to hive and how to load data into hive table.When i check in Internet i found using Load  and also using Insert statement.
Not sure which one i need to use and also what is the difference between each one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloudera hadoop : 
1)
.A Download the JSON serde from http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3/ according to CDH version you are using.

B.Add this jar to hive aux jar path or in hive session by adding "add jar" statement

C.CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE data_json(name string, address string, reference map,contact_no string)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'

STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/hdfs/path/forjsonfile/';

Assuming the data are stored in the form of json documents.

2. There is difference between LOAD & INSERT command

   A) We can LOAD the data to hive warehouse from local path or hdfs path using load statement 
   ex. LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/path/to/file' INTO table "tbl_name" while using INSERT statement we can copy the relevant data into our table like
   INSERT OVERWRITE table 'tbl_name" SELECT * FROM "other_table"

   B) Using load command we are actually moving the file from hdfs into hive warehouse while in INSERT command we are only copying the data.